# How to hide a block in thymeleaf if a user is authorized on the site?

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

How to hide in a thymeleaf block if a user is logged in and has already received any role.I want the login icon to be visible only if the user is not logged in. I know that blocks can be shown only to those users who have a role, but how to do the opposite?

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
   <a th:href="@{/forLogin}">Login</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the standard `!` NOT operator? `<div sec:authorize="! hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">` --- Or spelling it out? `<div sec:authorize="not hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">`

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I tried the first option, but due to inattention I put the sign in the wrong place. Therefore, it did not work for me. Thanks again.